# WAMP not allowing phpMyAdmin access after re-install

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I installed WAMP a while back for Wordpress and it was set up and working fine but I didn't get very far with it. I wanted to start using this again but had forgotten a lot of how things worked and decided to start over with a fresh install. I installed the 64 bit version which is different from my original install. Everything is connecting ok except that the phpMyAdmin inputs my old login and passsword which doesn't work. 
I have searched online for ways to get rid of the old user info. I uninstalled the original WAMP from the control panel and moved the files to recycle bin. I uninstalled the new WAMP64 from the included uninstall file. I reinstalled WAMP64 and still the old login shows up in phpMyAdmin.
When i search for WAMP files it just shows the old WAMP folder in the recycle bin. The folder doesn't have any uninstall.exe type option like the WAMP64 did.

Can someone please help me figure out how to really remove all the old files or give me direction on what I can do to create a new user/password?

Answer (score 0):

On phpMyAdmin, go to 'Users' and 'check' the user you want to delete and click on the 'Go' button. This should solve your problem.